# Acrobat SDK - Retrieving PDF paths on open

Tags: javascript, pdf, directory, acrobat

I want to have a script, preferably folder-level, that runs in the background. Every time a PDF is opened, I want to get the file path to that PDF and save it to an array. The problem is that I have not seen any action listeners in the documentation. There is, however, an object called app.activeDocs that is the currently active documents.

```
var d = app.activeDocs;
var paths = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < d.length; i++) {
    paths.push(d[i].path);
}
```

But the catch is that, these documents are only active if opened using the app.open command and I would like it to recognize PDFs that are opened either through double-clicking the PDF or opened using file > open.

I'm wondering if this is possible to do using the Acrobat SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to write a JavaScript that would be loaded by Acrobat upon launch and that would then be called each time a document is opened.

If that is the case, search for the "Event" object in the Acrobat Javascript documentation. These events are triggered upon certain actions, one of which is document open:

```
This event is triggered whenever a document is opened. When a document is opened,
the document-level script functions are scanned and any exposed scripts are executed.
```

[This article](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=working_with_events_in_acrobat&gid=6823) explains about events as well and points to an example document.